# About location of android development tools (ADT)

Tags: android, eclipse, location, adt

Anybody can tell to me about location of ADT after installation.
I want to know, this tool will be saved in "android-sdk-windows" folder of Eclipse or another folder.

Comment: This seems to be rather a RTFM question, not one worth our brainpower imo.

Comment: your question has answered itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no a specific folder where you must put `android-sdk-windows`. The only thing you MUST do is configure your eclipse ADT plugin to point to that folder (where ever it is).

Answer (score 0):

I explain more about my question.

I have shared my `android-sdk` with some of my visitors (I put sdk on my web-host to be downloaded by my visitors because accessing to android website in my country is denied by Google). One of my visitors asked me a question where is the location of ADT.

and because I didn't know, I asked this question.